# Global Mu Online "The game client is loaded only through the official website"

Tags: technical-issues, mu-online

When I start the game through the [official website](http://muonline.webzen.com/main) I get the follow error: "The game is loaded only through the official Website" even thought I'm starting from the official website.

When I click "game start" the launcher restart and I need to click it again to start the game, and I believe that it may be the cause of the error.

Am I missing something?

i found this: http://forum.ragezone.com/f196/start-game-launcher-website-gmo-883531/ but i don't understand the type of language or way to run it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found out a way to fix this, go to the mu folder, for example:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\WEBZEN\Mu

and make sure in `main.exe`, `"Run this program in compatibility mode" is set as "Windows XP (Service Pack 3)"`, and `"Run this program as an administrator"` is set as-well

then click on <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and write:

> C:\ProgramData\WEBZEN\BrowserPlugIns

then, on `CMStarterCore.exe` do the same

[image: Click here to see the image]

Comment: what if you have download mu in D: drive?

Comment: what `D:` drive?

Comment: @sub Then go to `D:\Program Files (x86)\WEBZEN\Mu` instead?

Comment: as @SevenSidedDie said, go to `D:\Program Files (x86)\WEBZEN\Mu` and when doing Windows+R and going to `C:\ProgramData\WEBZEN\BrowserPlugIns`, probably the folder keeps the same, but the best thing to do , is to try `C:\ProgramData\WEBZEN\BrowserPlugIns` and `D:\ProgramData\WEBZEN\BrowserPlugIns`, if it opens a folder with `CMStarterCore.exe` , it's probably that folder.  


The `C:\Program Files (x86)\WEBZEN\Mu` depends on Mu install location, and `C:\ProgramData\WEBZEN\BrowserPlugIns` depends on windows installed driver.

Answer (score 0):

Game directory : "main" >compatibilty> xp service pack 3 and admin

Program Data > Webzen > Browser Plugins > CMStarterCore > Do the same thing as main .